# Laravel: Refreshing page popups 'Confirm Form Submission'

Tags: php, laravel

On the first page, a user fills up a form, clicks the submit button to POST submit the data to `http://domain.com/somepage`. Upon processing the data, a second page `http://domain.com/somepage` loads. When refreshing the second page, I get the popup `Confirm Form Submission`! Why does this happen and how do I prevent this? *(Assuming this behavior is usually unwanted)*

[image]

**Form submitted to this route**

```
Route::post('/somepage', function() {
    $query = Input::get('query');
    return Redirect::to('/somepage')
            ->with('query', $query);
});
```

**Final page**

```
Route::get('/somepage', function() {
    $query = Session::get('query');
    return View::make('somepage')
                ->with('query', $query);
});
```

Comment: Is it a search like form or is it a real form to update for instance a user profile? (Each of those have different recommended approaches to avoid this)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to return the user to the get method after the post, so there seems to be a loop. How about you do your logic in a controller and pass the data from there instead, you can have more control this way.